# How can i detect which key was pressed on textfield's keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to make it not allow write many 0's if before 0 is nothing.
Is there any method of textfield?

Comment: you can get this  in textfield delegate of `textfieldshouldcharatrange`

Comment: you have to check that in - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{ } this method

Answer (score 1):

Modify this sample code as per your requirement.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@" "]) // Preventing Spaces here {
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right way, but it ignores the case when the user pastes text in the textfield. The pasted text can contain spaces so `[string isEqualToString:@" "]` would not be enough.

Comment: Its not a solution. Its just a sample code to let him know this delegate method of textfield for his requirement.